# Modify the color scale in ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, color, options

I'm trying to get the following intensity map with the same style and colors

[image]

But the closest I got was using SolarColors in Mathematica

```
DensityPlot[combinedFunction[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 10}, ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", 
 Exclusions -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotLegends -> True]
```

and I get

[image]

Could you please suggest me how to get a darker shade of SolarColors or the same theme I am looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own `ColorFunction` using `Blend`

```
H[x_, y_] := 10^3 1/(32 \[Pi] (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^3);
G[x_, y_] := 10^3 (1/(32 \[Pi]^2 (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^3)) ArcTan[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/Sqrt[4 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2]] - 10^3 Sqrt[4 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2]/(128 \[Pi]^2 (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2);
combinedFunction[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{G[x, y], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 2}, {H[x, y], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > 2}}]

DensityPlot[combinedFunction[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, Black}, {0.3, Darker@Red}, {0.6, Orange}, {.9, Yellow}, {1, White}}, #1] &), Exclusions -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotLegends -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 1;
DensityPlot[1/(x^2 + y^2), {x, -n, n}, {y, -n, n},
 ClippingStyle -> Darker @ Darker @ Red,
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Black, Darker @ Red, Yellow}, #1] &),
 Exclusions -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 PlotLegends -> True]
```

[image]